# how to make JButton changes the location of the text inside JLabel

Tags: java, swing, animation, jbutton, jlabel

how can i set JButton that changes the JLabel location on the JPanel when it pressed?
how to implement the actionlistener for this on the JButton?

Comment: Is the question "How to implement an action listener?" or "How to change a JLabel location?"

Comment: I'd be concerned with the fact that you want to move a label. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add the action listener to the button first

```
button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
```

Next you want to create the custom class

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == button) {
                 label.setLocation(xValue, yValue);
            }
     }
}
```

Change the xValue/yValue to the x and y values that you want the label to change to.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You can implement the `ActionListener` interface on your `JPanel` so that you can have access to the fields and methods to control other elements of your UI, like the `JLabel` you want to move.

Comment: I know you can, but I was providing another way to do it :)

Comment: My comment was intended for the OP to use in his specific case, it's just that I think it was better to post it where the info was.